# Why does `echo 0 >> /dev/mydevice` trigger `unlocked_ioctl` in linux driver

Tags: linux-kernel, driver, ioctl

I am writing a basic test driver for linux. I have implemented a basic `driver_open()`, `driver_read()`, `driver_write()`, and `driver_release()` methods in the `fops` structure, but I have also implemented a simple `unlocked_ioctl()` method (also in `fops`) as well.

When I test the driver using `echo 'test' >> /dev/mydevice` I notice the in addition to the `driver_open()` and `driver_write()` methods being called, the `unlocked_ioctl()` method is also being called?

Is this the expected behaviour? I would have thought `unlocked_ioctl()` would only have been called if this was called directly using the correct magic number and `ioctl()` method from a user application?

Comment: What is the output of `strace sh -c 'echo test >> /dev/mydevice'`?

Comment: `>>` means append to file, while `>` means write to file from beginning. They will not behave the same way.

Comment: There is no registration of "magic number" to the device driver. In theory, it could handle any ioctl command code (although some common ioctl command codes will be intercepted before they reach your driver).

Comment: It was probably a `TCGETS` ioctl command, used by the C runtime library to check if the device is a TTY or not. If the ioctl command is handled with no error, the file descriptor is assumed to be connected to a TTY. This affects the choice of standard I/O stream buffering used for a `FILE` connected to the file descriptor.

Comment: Thanks, so its expected behaviour, depending on the C runtime implementation?